# Bitrate Switching in xml playlist not loading video

Tags: xml, jwplayer, playlist, bitrate

Using JW Player ver 5.4 and JW Embedder. Plugins are grid by Dabbler and fbit (Facebook). The Bitrate switching is not working. Does work fine for one video with HTML5 Video tag. When more than one video, it only shows the first video pic. Works fine with no bitrate switching.

### Code - HTML5

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jwplayer/jwplayer.js"></script>
<video id="container"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
jwplayer("container").setup({
    flashplayer: "jwplayer/player.swf",
    streamer: "rtmp://server/location/",
    playlistfile: "playlists/playlist.xml",
    plugins: {
        grid: { rows: 4, distance: 60, horizontalmargin: 75, verticalmargin: 75 },
        fbit: { link: "http://www.domain.com" }
    },
    height: 375,
    width: 850,
    dock: true
});
</script>
```

### XML - ATOM/MEDIA

xmlns:jwplayer='http://developer.longtailvideo.com/trac/wiki/FlashFormats'>
  Demostration Playlist

Video 1
    
    
   
   
   
   
   
   
    
    rtmp
    rtmp://server/location/
  
  
    Video 2
    
    
   
   
   
   
   
   
    
    rtmp
    rtmp://server/location/

have tried it with both video and div tags for the container. Div tag just shows a blank video area and a Null exception on Line 1 char 1863, this is probably the jwplayer.js file.  XML is larger than this, this is to give you a brief syntax of my code and xml. I have searched for over 6 hrs on both longtail and search engine searches. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dabber has confirmed error with Grid plugin with bitrate switching and is working with developers to release an update shortly

Answer (score 0):

I found [your problem](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/forums/jw-player/setup-issues-and-embedding/17151/bitrate-switching-not-working-right-with-playlist) site referenced on the Longtail site.

http://www.omniadiamond.com/index.php/client-list-rewrite?player=1

I tried using the **[jw-player-setup-wizard](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player-setup-wizard)** with a **flvplayer with an rss playlist** and your [playlist-test.xml](http://data.omniadiamond.com/playlists/test_playlist.xml) and there appears to be some problem with your media server (I'm not saying that is the only problem but it is a start!)

Comment: it is not an issue with the media server. Works fine without the grid plugin. The issue is with the grid plugin. If you viewed the longtail site, Ethan from longtail had mentioned that there is a flash error.

Comment: Happy to hear that you have got to the bottom of it.